# checking if arg was passed when default is set with python optparse

Tags: python, command-line, build, arguments, scons

I want to check if an arg was actually passed on the command line when there is a default value for that arg.

Specifically in my case, I am using SCons and scons has a class which inherits from pythons optparse. So my code is like this so far:

```
from SCons.Environment import Environment
from SCons.Script.SConsOptions import Parser

MAIN_ENV = Environment() 
argparser = Parser(MAIN_ENV._get_major_minor_revision(SCons.__version__))
print(argparser.parse_args())
```

Which prints all the args with the values, but I can't tell if one of the args was set or just has the default value in place. In the case I am looking at SCons 'num_jobs' option, which defaults to 1. I would like to check if the user supplied a num_jobs value, and use that if so, or otherwise just set num_jobs to the number of CPUs reported by the system.

I can use sys.argv like this, but would prefer a cleaner option using the option parser:

```
###################################################
# Determine number of Jobs
# start by assuming num_jobs was not set
NUM_JOBS_SET = False
if GetOption("num_jobs") == 1:
    # if num_jobs is the default we need to check sys.argv
    # to see if the user happened to set the default
    for arg in sys.argv:
        if arg.startswith("-j") or arg.startswith("--jobs"):
            if arg == "-j" or arg == "--jobs":
                if(int(sys.argv[sys.argv.index(arg)+1]) == 1):
                    NUM_JOBS_SET = True
            else:
                if arg.startswith("-j"):
                    if(int(arg[2:]) == 1):
                        NUM_JOBS_SET = True
else:
    # user must have set something if it wasn't default
    NUM_JOBS_SET = True

# num_jobs wasn't specificed so let use the
# max number since the user doesn't seem to care
if not NUM_JOBS_SET:
    NUM_CPUS = get_num_cpus()
    print("Building with " + str(NUM_CPUS) + " parallel jobs")
    MAIN_ENV.SetOption("num_jobs", NUM_CPUS)
else:
    # user wants a certain number of jobs so do that
    print("Building with " + str(GetOption('num_jobs')) + " parallel jobs")
```

I tried using pythons OptionParser, but if I call parse_args() from the OptionParser from python inside a scons script, SCons parser doesn't seem to work, it fails to recognize valid options.

If someone has an example of how to check if the arg was passed with just pythons optparse, that should be sufficient for me to work into scons option parser.

Comment: It sounds like what you need here is a different default.

Comment: @user2357112 I am using scons here, and I don't think I can change the default of the arg that is part of that module.

Comment: So, as a user of your build process I'll be surprised why a simple "scons" suddenly decides to use all available cores. Also, if you have linking steps involved in your build this might give people further problems, because then they **have to** use the "`-j`" option to keep the number of parallel tasks down. Watch out that you're not handling in one inconvenience for the other.

Comment: @dirkbaechle with the number of cores available in modern machines, I can't imagine anyone being happy with 1 core building, so I would say in most cases they would be using the j option anyways. I agree that people unfamiliar with this build could be surprised when all the available cores are used without specifying, but after that they would know what to expect. To me it seems more convenient to assume I want to build as fast as possible, and I will limit the resources if needed. I am not sure what relationship you are referring to with linking and number of jobs.

Comment: *SCons* will not only run the compilation of files in parallel, but linking too. The latter consumes a lot more memory and we've had several users reporting large builds to fail when using "-j" with a too high number in the past.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593257/how-to-know-if-optparse-option-was-passed-in-the-command-line-or-as-a-default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this question linked in the comment: [How to know if optparse option was passed in the command line or as a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593257/how-to-know-if-optparse-option-was-passed-in-the-command-line-or-as-a-default)

I was able to use this for my case in SCons:

```
from SCons.Environment import Environment
from SCons.Script.SConsOptions import Parser

###################################################
# Determine number of Jobs
# start by assuming num_jobs was not set
opts_no_defaults = optparse.Values()
parser = Parser(MAIN_ENV._get_major_minor_revision(SCons.__version__))
__, args = parser.parse_args(values=opts_no_defaults)
opts = optparse.Values(parser.get_default_values().__dict__)
opts._update_careful(opts_no_defaults.__dict__)

# num_jobs wasn't specificed so let use the
# max number since the user doesn't seem to care
if not hasattr(opts_no_defaults, parser.get_option('--jobs').dest):
    NUM_CPUS = get_num_cpus()
    ColorPrinter().InfoPrint("Building with " + str(NUM_CPUS) + " parallel jobs")
    MAIN_ENV.SetOption("num_jobs", NUM_CPUS)
else:
    # user wants a certain number of jobs so do that
    ColorPrinter().InfoPrint(
        "Building with " + str(GetOption('num_jobs')) + " parallel jobs")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will solve your problem or not, but you can write decorator and in decorator you can find parameter passed or not.

I am providing basic example.

```
def deco(fun):
    def wraper(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'name' in kwargs:
            print('Will use default parameter');
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)

    return wraper

@deco
def greet(name = 'World'):
    print('Hello '+name)

greet(name = 'Praveen')
greet()
```